# Browser-like tabs in Vue - how?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, tabs, router

I'm planning on an academics organizer application where you can add tabs much like you can add tabs in a browser, but it's in the context of the application. Each tab has its own history, route, navigation, etc.

I thought this would be trivial to implement with vue-router but thinking about it a little more I have no idea how to map router links to tabs that can change as routes are usually just set in stone.

I also thought about creating a separate router for each tab, but that also seems a bit funny. Can someone help me out?

EDIT: It's important to note that the application is *not* actually a web browser. I would just like browser-like tabs, but in the context of an academics-organizer-application-thing.

Comment: It's unclear how it's related to a router. Are tabs supposed to be tied to browser url and history?

Comment: Not necessarily browser URL, but history, yeah. I wanted to make tabs that acted like tabs of a browser - that is, each has their own route inside the application, e.g. one tab might be displaying application settings, another tab might be displaying my calendar, and I can add new tabs which I can navigate to different parts of my app, and I can go through these tabs' histories much like the back-next buttons of a browser.

Comment: It's important to note that the application is *not* actually a web browser. I would just like browser-like tabs, but in the context of an academics-organizer-application-thing.

Comment: Then a router with in-memory history is not a bad idea. Otherwise you end up reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't need a router to do that you can simply use v-if and v-else on a specific property that sets the active tab

Comment: The problem would be how to separate history / navigation for each tab. I want it to be like a browser-like experience where each tab is isolated from another.

Comment: @Voltaire You can create a component for each tab and use local storage to store the info you need and also take the active tab from the route parameter, there's a lot of possibilities to fix each issue one by one but of course not everything can be done to make it same as the browser but walk step by step and search to fix every issue u face.For the history you can use vuex and state management to save the prev and next as arrays for example

Answer (score 1):

**First idea.**

It may be better to use some existed layout framework for tabs logic. For example [Golden Layout](https://golden-layout.com/)

And when tab opens you can bootstrap into this tab vue.js app with vue-router in ["abstract" mode](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#mode).

For state managment you can use event bus or vuex. But it has to be the only one across the whole app.

**Second idea.**

If bootstrapping of several vue.js apps looks like overengineering, then you could create component which implements basic functions for history / navigation. This component have to wrap the content of each your tab.

Comment: The second idea is probably my best bet, as booting separate Vue instances in each app seem like way too much for what I want.